# Find minimum value in row on datasheet

Tags: ms-access, formatting, conditional-statements, datasheet

I want to highlight the column with the minimum value. To achieve that i want to use conditional formating with the following formular:

```
In Column i
Hightlight cell if following function is true:
[date i] <= Minimum([date1],[date2],[date3],[date4])
```

This formular doesn't work. The Function min() finds the minimum value of a column. I need a Function that gets multiple values of a row and returns the minimal value.

I know that i could do something like

```
[date i] <= [date1] and [date i] <= [date2] and [date i] <= [date3] and [date i] <= [date4]
```

but it wouldn't be clean code.

[Picture of the according menu in Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvkQP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

1. UNION query to rearrange the fields into normalized structure then use the UNION query in an aggregate query with the Min() function
2. VBA custom function